# Can I add numerically the values of two arrays using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, vector, operators

If I have two numeric arrays, for example `double[] a, b` and I want to produce a third array with each element being the addition of `a` and `b` I can do it with a loop

```
double[] a, b, c
// fill in a, b and initialize c
for(int i=0; i<c.Length; i++)
{
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

So the question is; is there a way to do with with LINQ instead of a loop?

PS. Assume I already have a binary operator `Func<double,double,doube> add = (x,y)=>x+y;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is:

```
c = a.Select((x, i) => x + b[i]).ToArray();
```

This is an overload of LINQ Select extension method which takes a `Func<TSource, int, TResult>`
where the int argument is the index of the TSource element. This way you can use it to access the i-th element of b as well, but only if `b.Length >= a.Length`, otherwise you could end up with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks, this what I want since I use VS2008.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you just want the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method:

```
var result = a.Zip(b, add).ToArray();
```

(Of course, this will still loop internally - but not in your code.)

EDIT: `Zip` is only available in .NET 4 and above, but [Eric Lippert's blog post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx) includes sample source code... or you can use [my Edulinq implementation](https://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/Zip.cs) (see [corresponding blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-35-zip.aspx)).

Comment: Would `add` be something like `(a,b) => a+b`?

Comment: Is it .NET 4 and up only? Otherwise yes this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @ja72: Looks like it's. NET 4+. This might help you: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqZip35.aspx

Comment: @ja72: Yes, it's in .NET 4. See edits for a couple of places you can get an implementation.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush: There's a bug in that implementation - it doesn't validate its `func` parameters. (It also uses different parameter names to the full .NET version, which is a pity.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's why you're the Skeet!

Comment: How do you zip two arrays of different lengths to get an array as long as the longest one of the two (assuming + 0 for indices > shortest.Length)? e.g. {1, 2, 3} zip {1, 2, 3, 4} -> {2, 4, 6, 4}